# activateIgnoringOtherApps and makeKeyAndOrderFront not working after NSWindow is closed

Tags: macos, cocoa, nswindow, nsstoryboard

I started with a storyboard project. and I put Menubar item.
When the menubar item is clicked, the following method is triggered in AppDelegate.swift.

```
func setWindowVisible() {
    NSApp.activateIgnoringOtherApps(ture)
    NSApp.mainWindow?.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)
}
```

this brings my app in front. But once I click the close button, the red one on the window, it never works.

It used to work in non-storyboard based projects no matter I close the window.

I have set

```
NSApp.mainWindow?.releasedWhenClosed = false
```

in applicationDidFinishLaunching()

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Setting `releasedWhenClosed` in `applicationDidFinishLaunching` has no effect as the `mainWindow` property is nil at this moment. → The window is created after this method is executed.

The `releasedWhenClosed` is defaulted to false anyway when the window is created in Interface Builder.

The mainWindow property is probably nil after closing the window, because then there is no mainWindow anymore. From the docs:

> The value in this property is nil when the app’s storyboard or nib file has not yet finished loading. It might also be nil when the app is inactive or hidden.

I was able to show the window again (after closing) by accessing the window from within the `windows` array of `NSApp`.

```
NSApp.activateIgnoringOtherApps(true)
NSApp.windows[0].makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)
```

In case you have more than one window, you need to find the right one in the array..

Comment: still no luck. I have one window which the xcode template provides

Comment: Can you print the windows array?

Comment: I have just solved.  var window: NSWindow!  with this property,  window = NSApp.mainWindow!  in applicationDidBecomeActive(),  then self.window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self) in my method.

Comment: But I do not know if the best place for window = NSApp.mainWindow! is inside applicationDidBecomeActive(). any suggestion do you have sir?

Comment: I guess this is ok as long as you only have one window. When it changes, this code might break.

Comment: then it would be ok for my project this time. your mentioning about window creation after applicationDidFinishLaunching helped me. thank you.

Comment: has been changed to:  NSApp.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)

Comment: NSApp.activateIgnoringOtherApps(true). The absence of this line caused me troubles (window front but not key) which are now solved. Thank U.

Answer (score 1):

Want to pull the answer by Kyle KIM into it's own answer, as the above solution with array access caused an exception for me.

In my use case, I'm using [this keyboard shortcuts library](https://github.com/sindresorhus/KeyboardShortcuts) to bring the app to foreground.

I'm also using this alongside the new **SwiftUI app** feature, and thankfully it all works together -- this will invoke again even if you click the close button.

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

var window: NSWindow?

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ notification: Notification) {
    self.window = NSApp.mainWindow
}

func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    KeyboardShortcuts.onKeyUp(for: .toggleApp) {
        if !NSApp.isActive || !(self.window?.isKeyWindow ?? false) {
            NSApp.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
            self.window?.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)
        } else {
            print("App already active")
        }
    }
}
}
```

!NSApp.isActive and the key window check are both required because when a user clicks the "close button" the widow is *no longer key* but still *active*. The app remains active until they click on a different app. You can see this happening with the focus colors of windows.

Note that this AppDelegate isn't the main entry point in my app, it's used alongside swiftUI:

```
@main
struct MainApp: App {
    @NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate

    var body: some Scene {...}
}
```

Comment: For a SwiftUI app, this was exactly my problem and fixed it for me too.